How does a UK expat regain residency status?
Suppose a person has a UK citizenship from a UK parent but they themselves were born an grew up in another country.
As far as I know, if they go to the UK for a certain amount of time and then return to their country of birth, if they have children, the children are considered citizens. If I am not mistaken, this status is called residency status.
What are the conditions for this person to be considered a resident as I have described it? Or if it works differently to how I have described it, how does it work?
I have seen some sources say that a person stays in UK for half a year and others anywhere up to three years.

How exactly are the immigration agency consultants you paid reluctant to share the information and/or advice you ostensibly paid them for?

I'm unsure what you are asking.
If you are asking "In what way..." They said that it was out of the scope of what they did which was helping non-UK-passport-holders get permanent residence.
If you are asking "How could they do that?" that then I don't know but I am speculating that it is not something I need them for since it is not about immigration. Perhaps they said it was out of scope for other reasons (apart from the obvious that it's simply not something that these companies do).
To be exact, I paid one and got free advice from another.

I understand what you are asking now, I think. I didn't say that I paid them for information, I said that I paid for a consultation. The consultation was to provide me with options and that didn't include any information about an existing citizen gaining residency.

So you didn't ask the question you're actually most interested in answering? Well, not their fault. If you're paying to answer questions - ask the ones you want answered.

To the OP: questions asking for legal advice specific to your real-life situation are off-topic here. You could try editing or re-posting a more generic question. A warning to anyone in the UK thinking of posting an answer: it is a criminal offence to give immigration advice unless you are qualified to do so (e.g. you are a solicitor).

You better check with a lawyer, but I believe that the child of a “UK citizen by descent” is a UK citizen if born in the UK, and unrelated to the UK if born outside the UK. And if the spouse who has the citizenship by descent is the mother, then she should have no problems being in the UK at the time of birth. Again, check with a lawyer.

Could you make clear who is the mother, because it would be important.

Residency is unrelated to citizenship
In the UK, the formal name for residency is “indefinite leave to remain” and means basically what it says: you can remain living and working in the UK indefinitely, but you aren’t a citizen. You can apply for residency after lawfully living in the UK for at least 5 years.
If you are a citizen, you always have the right to live and work in the UK, among other things, such as the right to vote in UK elections. Citizenship by descent is complicated and depends on when you were born, whether your father or your mother was a British citizen, whether they were married at the time of your birth, etc. If you are claiming Northern Irish citizenship then a different set of rules apply.

There's an incorrect use of terminology here. Indefinite leave to remain is just that. Residency is something else. It's about where you are living as your main home. For example, I can be a UK citizen, but non-resident. I can have indefinite leave to remain, but be non-resident either because I haven't arrived in the UK yet or because (for up to 2 years) I've moved out again. I can be resident with just "leave to remain" (i.e. non-indefinite). Another way of looking at it is that [indefinite] leave to remain means you can live in the UK, while residency means you do live there.

One consequence of the difference is that residency usually has tax implications, while indefinite leave to remain without residency usually does not.

@JBentley in the context of the question, that’s not what’s being asked.

I think that is closer to what I was asking. It wouldn't make sense to get indefinite leave to remain for someone who is already a citizen. What is the name of the requirement in section 3 (5) (b)?
https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1981/61/section/3

You better check with a lawyer, but I believe that the child of a “UK citizen by descent” is a UK citizen if born in the UK, and unrelated to the UK if born outside the UK. And if the spouse who has the citizenship by descent is the mother, then she should have no problems being in the UK at the time of birth. Again, check with a lawyer.
What you suggest is not going to work. There’s no way to change your status from “citizen by descent” to citizen. Almost everyone can become a citizen if they try hard enough and pay enough, but citizens by descent can’t.
You have the right as a citizen by descent to enter the UK, for example for a holiday. From there to resident status is hard.
But that is all not needed at all: All you need is that the birth happens in the Uk. Which a mother who is citizen by descent can easily do. (And if the mother gets resident status but then makes the mistake of going on holiday abroad when the baby is born, that baby is not British). What counts is where the birth happens.
I forgot: The exact rules for who is “citizen by descent” have changed in the past, so check whether you are one.

A British citizen by descent can become a British citizen otherwise than by descent by renouncing their citizenship and then going through the process to immigrate and naturalize. But unfortunately it is true that if a British citizen by descent lives in the UK for most of their life and then just happens to give birth while living outside the UK, the child isn't a British citizen. I assume they have some exception if the citizen was in the military or something at the time of birth.
